# JQuery - How to get url params from last requested server url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

How to **get url parameters** from last requested server URL using JQuery?

Comment: explain "url parameters". Are you talking about query string?

Comment: What do you mean by "last requested server URL"?

Comment: my last server request

Comment: `"my last server request"` from what?  From a single page requested via ajax?  Last server request from any browser in the world?  Last server request from any page within a single browser.  This question is entirely ambiguous and needs clarification as all three cases I asked about have entirely different answers.  Also, when you respond to a question from a particular person, if you want them to see the response, you need to target them by putting @username at the start of the comment.  This will notify them that there is a comment directed at them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the params from the query string, but that often has nothing to do with the last requested server URL. One page can request hundreds of URLS from images to CSS and other JS files to template partials to hitting analytics and APIs.

You'd need to build an AJAX decorator that caches urls and then write a getter to fetch the most recently added one. Parsing the query string is trivial. Checkout [URI.js](http://medialize.github.io/URI.js/) for an assistance lib.

Answer (score 0):

previous url

```
document.referrer;
```

now you have previous url, you can get params from here